# AJAX call only works once with $(document).on('click')

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that displays entries of a database. The user is able to open a popup menu for each row. One of the options is to delete a database entry and the table should refresh accordingly via an AJAX call.

I'm doing an AJAX call on a HTML page as soon as someone clicks the `#delete-toggle` in the `table-popup` (the `table-popup` is a div that appears when someone clicks the `table-edit-button` in the table that exists in each row of the table):

```
  <div class="table-popup">
    <ul>
      <li id="edit-toggle">Bearbeiten</li>
      <li id="favorite-toggle">Zu Favoriten hinzufügen</li>
      <li>Datei öffnen</li>
      <li>Im Ordner öffnen</li>
      <li id="delete-toggle">Löschen</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
    <h2 class="main-content-header">Datenbank</h2>
    <div id="table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-row" tabindex="1">
            <th class="fixed-header"></th>
            <th>Dateiname</th>
            <th>Benutzer</th>
            <th>Erstelldatum</th>
            <th>Änderungsdatum</th>
            <th>Erste Zeile</th>
            <th>Kategorie</th>
            <th>Projekt</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        include_once('connect.php');
        $result = $connect->query("SELECT file.name AS 'filename', file.description AS 'filedescription', category.name AS 'categoryname', project.name AS 'projectname', user.name AS 'username', idFile
          FROM file, category, project, file_has_project, file_has_category, user, user_has_project, user_has_category
          WHERE file.idFile = file_has_project.file_idFile AND file_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND file.idFile = file_has_category.file_idFile AND file_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND user.idUser = user_has_project.user_idUser AND user_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND user.idUser = user_has_category.user_idUser AND user_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND user.idUser = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'
          ORDER BY file.name ASC");
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          echo "<tbody>";
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr class='".$row['idFile']." table-row' tabindex='1'>";
            echo "<th class='table-edit-button fixed-header'><img src='images/open.gif' /></th>";
            echo "<td>".$row['filename']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
            echo "<td>-</td>";
            echo "<td>-</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['filedescription']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['categoryname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['projectname']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          }
          echo "</tbody>";
        }
        ?>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the function that does the AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fileID, fileName, fileDescription, fileCategory, fileProject, projectID, categoryID;
  $('.table-edit-button').click(function() {
    fileID = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[0];
  });

  //Delete file entries
  $(document).on("click", "#delete-toggle", function() {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: 'ajax-delete.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { fileID : fileID, deleteID : 'indexFile' },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.main-content').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And here is the page that receives the AJAX call:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('connect.php');

if ($_POST['deleteID'] == 'indexFile') {
  $connect->query("DELETE FROM file_has_project WHERE file_idFile = '".$_POST['fileID']."'");
  $connect->query("DELETE FROM file_has_category WHERE file_idFile = '".$_POST['fileID']."'");
  $connect->query("DELETE FROM file WHERE idFile ='".$_POST['fileID']."'");

  echo '<h2 class="main-content-header">Datenbank</h2>
  <div id="table">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="table-row" tabindex="1">
          <th class="fixed-header"></th>
          <th>Dateiname</th>
          <th>Benutzer</th>
          <th>Erstelldatum</th>
          <th>Änderungsdatum</th>
          <th>Erste Zeile</th>
          <th>Kategorie</th>
          <th>Projekt</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>';
      $result = $connect->query("SELECT file.name AS 'filename', file.description AS 'filedescription', category.name AS 'categoryname', project.name AS 'projectname', user.name AS 'username', idFile
        FROM file, category, project, file_has_project, file_has_category, user, user_has_project, user_has_category
        WHERE file.idFile = file_has_project.file_idFile AND file_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND file.idFile = file_has_category.file_idFile AND file_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND user.idUser = user_has_project.user_idUser AND user_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND user.idUser = user_has_category.user_idUser AND user_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND user.idUser = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'
        ORDER BY file.name ASC");
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<tbody>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<tr class='".$row['idFile']." table-row' tabindex='1'>";
          echo "<th class='table-edit-button fixed-header'><img src='images/open.gif' /></th>";
          echo "<td>".$row['filename']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
          echo "<td>-</td>";
          echo "<td>-</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['filedescription']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['categoryname']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['projectname']."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
      }
  echo "  </table>";
  echo "</div>";

  $connect->close();
}
?>
```

This is the function that handles the animation to display the `table-popup` (wrapped in `$(document).ready`):

```
  function disablePopup() {
    $('.table-popup').hide(100);
  }

  function enablePopup(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var buttonOffset = $(this).offset();
    $('.table-popup').css({
      top: buttonOffset.top + 10,
      left: buttonOffset.left +10
    });
    $('.table-popup').show(100);
  }

  //Disable Table Popup Menu
  $(document).on("click", disablePopup);

  //Enable Table Popup Menu
  $(document).on("click", ".table-edit-button", enablePopup);
```

The problem that I'm having is that everything works as expected the first time it gets executed. But when I want to do it a second time without refreshing the whole page it doesn't work. The `click` event gets fired I tested it with an `alert` but the AJAX call doesn't get executed. I have to refresh the whole page and then it works again.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347229/jquery-ajax-call-on-click-only-works-once) I thought it would be fixed when I changed all the `.click` to `$(document).on('click')` but that didn't fix it. As you can see all the relevant parts are like this. And adding `cache: false` to the AJAX call didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you bind the edit button on document ready so when you replace the html table with the Ajax call, they are no longer bound. You need to use event delegation or bind the buttons when the Ajax call is returned.

```
$('.table-edit-button').click(function() {
```

needs to be

```
$(document).on("click", '.table-edit-button', function() {
```

Comment: But I have that. ...?

Comment: no you don't have it in both places....not for the button click as seen with the code `$('.table-edit-button').click(function() {` where you set the fileId variable's value.

Comment: Oh I see it now. Will try that.

Comment: It works now. Thank you so much! :) I was so focused on all the other functions that I didn't see that I forgot to change it there.

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call, Try below,

```
//Delete file entries
$("#delete-toggle").on("click", function() {
 $.ajax({
   cache: false,
   url: 'ajax-delete.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: { fileID : fileID, deleteID : 'indexFile' },
   success: function(data) {
     $('.main-content').html(data);
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Care to share an explanation? Because the click function is working even on every subsequent click. The AJAX call is not working

Answer (score 0):

When you call some jquery event handler in ajax content then you need you code like this

```
$(document).on("click", '.table-edit-button', function(){});
```

if we do use on it is fire no issue it is in page or ajax content. earlier we use live but it is depreciated and now it is replace via `.on` so use .ON and your ajax call working 100%